How to Align Memory to Cache Line Using Boost Interprocess Shared Memory
I am writing a Boost.Interprocess code for shared memory between two processes. I am using managed_shared_memory. I'm initializing the memory using boost::interprocess::open_or_create, and I am allocating memory in it using find_or_construct, like this:
auto data_ptr = segment.find_or_construct<Data>("data")[max_elements]();

I am using find_or_construct so that one process initializes the memory and another process receives the data structure. All of this is atomic.
I want to ensure that data_ptr is aligned to a cache line, meaning it must start at an address that is a multiple of 64 bytes (on my system). How can I achieve this alignment?
Additional Information:
The system cache line size is 64 bytes.
I'm using Boost.Interprocess for shared memory management.
I looked into Boost.Interprocess documentation but couldn't find a direct way to specify memory alignment for find_or_construct. It will be really helpful if I can get some other way to align memory with Boost, and ensure one process initializes the memory while another process receives the data structure, without any synchronization issues.

It max_elements a compile-time constant?

yes, max_elements is a compile time constant

Then you can write a type struct DataArray { alignas(64) Data data[max_elements]; }; and then use auto data_ptr = segment.find_or_construct<DataArray>("data")().data;, assuming that the library handles overaligned types correctly (which I hope it would, but don't know).

Note that this has been fixed in 1.87.0.

segment_manager nows uses a new implementation that supports overaligned types and fixes some existing bugs. You can obtain the pre-Boost 1.87 ABI #defining BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SEGMENT_MANAGER_ABI to 1 before including Boost.Interprocess headers.

